# Why is the 7 yr old cat pooping all over the house?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, defecation

This is not a new thing.  He has loose stools uses the litter box.  There are several times he relieves himself wherever he happens to be when all he has to do is go to the box. He has 2 boxes and uses both for it all. I don't get it and would like some kind of input.  Thank you

Comment: for how long have this been going on,do you have other pets in the house.what does your vet say about this it might be a sign your cat is in pain.

Comment: I did have another cat at the same time this is has been going on.  The vet gave me antibiotic pills- I was only successful in getting 3 in him, after that I could not fool him or he just spit it out.  Are there injections instead?  I will be making appt with new vet about this as that will be the 3rd vet for same problem.